# React get value from select dropdown populated from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a select component:

```
<Select}>
    {data &&
        data.map((survey) => (
            <Option key={survey.id} value={survey.id}>
                {survey.name}
            </Option>
        ))
     }
</Select>
```

The data array is coming from an API fetch using axios, which is then saved in the state data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

How do I grab the selected value and display it?

I tried adding an `onChange` handler to the  component and save the `e.target.value` in a separate piece of state:

```
onChange={e => setInput(e?.target?.value)}
```

However, I'm getting an error that `value` is `undefined`. I suspect it's because the data hasn't loaded yet.

How do you get the selected value from the options when the options are coming from an API? (i.e., dynamic dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setData(e.target.value);
  };

   <select onChange={handleChange}>
      {dataArr &&
        dataArr.map((survey) => (
          <option key={survey.id} value={survey.id}>
            {survey.name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </select>
```

Example : [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sjnjjc?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it still says cannot read value of undefined. Just a reminder that the options themselves are coming from an API. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: The error only appears when I select an option from the list. The list itself is being populated without a problem

Comment: Did you try the example I shared ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new state and set it in `onChange` handler to show the selected data at somewhere else.

Define it as:

```
const [selectedValue,setSelectedValue] = useState()
```

Then, set it:

```
const handleChange = (e) => { 
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
}
```

it is now available to use anywhere in this component.

Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedValue,setSelectedValue] = useState()

// this useEffect is just a simulator for api response, you do not need this useEffect, 
// instead just call your api and set the data with your awaited response
  useEffect(()=>{ 
    setTimeout(()=> {
      setData([ 
        { name: 'first Option', id: 'ID of first option'},
        { name: 'Second Option', id: 'ID of second option' }
      ])
    },[2000])
  },[])

  const handleChange = (e) => { 
    console.log(e.target.value); // maybe print the value to check
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
  }
  
  return (<div>
    <select onChange={handleChange}>
      {data &&
        data.map((survey) => (
          <option key={survey.id} value={survey.id}>
            {survey.name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </select>
    {selectedValue ? <div>Selected value:  {selectedValue} </div> : ''}
  </div>
  );
}
```